# How to get max value in column on the basis of Verb using solr?

Tags: solr

I need to get grouping data using solr with high performance response.

Or how to get group data without using group ?

Comment: Please add something you have done or already with you now

Comment: I need to get grouping data using solr without uses of group query.
Or how to get group data without using group ?

Comment: So you want to get what `<feature>` gives you, without using said `<feature>`? You'll have to provide actual details about what you're trying to solve, why it doesn't work and what an alternative solution should have instead.

Comment: "docs": [           
      
      {
        "en": "Something to eat.",
        "es": "Comen!",
        "id": "1e8f31ae-e55a-4317-937e-8eda81c2a7e6",
        "_version_": 1533278652420063200,
        "type": "subtitle",
        "popularity": 0
      },
      {
        "en": "They eat and eat and eat and eat.",
        "es": "Comen y comen y comen y comen.",
        "id": "d0063bb2-d64b-45d8-acb4-d729d0acbad6",
        "_version_": 1533278744885592000,
        "type": "subtitle",
        "popularity": 0
      }];

Comment: after save data in sole shown like that and query is :---q=*%3A*&group=true&group.query=es%3A%22vuelo%22&group.query=es%3A%22vuelas%22&group.query=es%3A%22vuela%22&group.query=es%3A%22vol%C3%A9%22&group.query=es%3A%22volaste%22&group.query=es%3A%22vol%C3%B3%22&group.query=es%3A%22vuele%22&group.query=es%3A%22vueles%22&group.query=es%3A%22vuele%22&group.query=es%3A%22haya+volado%22&group.query=es%3A%22hayas+volado%22&group.query=es%3A%22haya+volado%22&group.limit=1&sort=popularity+desc

Comment: when i will select my all verb using interface so it takes a lot time to give response of this query. So what may be exact way to optimize this query to avoid group query.

Comment: E.g. My verb is en ---> Something to eat then its taking a lot time for response.